# Is there a way to store and process camera stream on Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: opencv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, object-detection

How can I record and process for object detection a surveillance camera stream to Google Cloud Storage 24/7 ?

Comment: Google Cloud Storage only "stores" the data. Then you need a process to "process" the data and perform what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc) ...

See: [Running OpenCV on Google Cloud Dataproc using Apache Spark](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/new-codelab-running-opencv-on-google-cloud-dataproc-using-apache-spark)
[Dataproc best practices guide](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/dataproc-best-practices-guide) explains the relation to Cloud Storage.